# Android:Espresso:WireMock java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/common/io/Resources;

Tags: android, android-espresso, wiremock

**Android Studio 3.2**.
I want to use **WireMock** in my Espresso's test.

In build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.KOTLIN_VERSION = '1.3.21'
    ext.ESPRESSO_VERSION = '3.2.0-alpha02'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$KOTLIN_VERSION"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

in app/build.gradle

```
android {
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myproject"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 6
        versionName "0.0.7"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
        androidTest.java.srcDirs += 'src/androidTest/kotlin'
    }


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.0@aar') { transitive = true; }

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.chauthai.swipereveallayout:swipe-reveal-layout:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.yuyh.json:jsonviewer:1.0.6'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$KOTLIN_VERSION"

    implementation project(':common')

    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$ESPRESSO_VERSION"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:$ESPRESSO_VERSION"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:$ESPRESSO_VERSION"

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.2-alpha02'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.2-alpha02'

    androidTestImplementation("com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock:2.18.0") {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
        exclude group: 'asm', module: 'asm'
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
        exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module:'guava'
    }

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Here my Espresso's test:

```
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.test.filters.SmallTest
import androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.onView
import androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.*
import androidx.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches
import androidx.test.espresso.intent.rule.IntentsTestRule
import androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.isDisplayed
import android.graphics.Color
import android.graphics.Typeface
import androidx.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.*
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.WireMockConfiguration.wireMockConfig
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.junit.WireMockRule

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class AddTraderActivityTest {

    @get:Rule
    var wireMockRule = WireMockRule(wireMockConfig().port(8081))

    @Test
    fun toolbarTitleTextViewText() {
        onView(withId(R.id.toolbaTitleTextView)).check(matches(withText(R.string.add_trader)))
    }

}
```

But I get error:

```
$ adb shell am instrument -w -r   -e debug false -e class 'com/myproject.android.activity.AddTraderActivityTest#toolbarTitleTextViewText' com/myproject.android.debug.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
Client not ready yet..
Started running tests

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/common/io/Resources;
at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.WireMockConfiguration.<init>(WireMockConfiguration.java:58)
at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.WireMockConfiguration.wireMockConfig(WireMockConfiguration.java:104)
at com/myproject.android.activity.AddTraderActivityTest.<init>(AddTraderActivityTest.kt:55)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:266)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:104)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:389)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1879)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.common.io.Resources" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/data/app/com/myproject.android.debug.test-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com/myproject.android.debug-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com/myproject.android.debug.test-2/lib/arm, /data/app/com/myproject.android.debug-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
... 30 more
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.io.Resources
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

Comment: you found any resolution this ?

Comment: facing the same issue. request you to post the solution if you got for this.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was removing the exclusion:
`exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module:'guava'` from the wiremock dependency implementation in app/build.gradle.

I googled for where `com.google.common.io.Resources` was coming from, and it was guava, so if you aren't including guava from another one of your project includes, you have to remove the exclusion.

Alternatively, I belive you could also add
`implementation "com.google.guava:guava:30.1-android"` to your Gradle file and it should also work (with the exclusion still in place).

Answer (score 1):

To explicitly use Wiremock in Espresso/Instrumented Tests, but exclude from unit tests (using Kotlin DSL)

```
androidTestApi("com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock:2.18.0") {
    exclude("org.apache.httpcomponents", "httpclient")
    exclude("org.ow2.asm", "asm")
    exclude("org.json", "json")
}
androidTestApi("org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1")
```